# User characteristics database schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I'm really battling an issue where I have a Users table that has a growing number of user characteristics (regligion, smoking preferences, etc). The strategy I've used thus far has been to add a column for each preference that keys off onto another table.

For example, if User XYZ has a RelgionId of 3, that could mean they're Christian. At runtime, if I need their religion, I join onto another table.

This strategy has worked so far. However, I'm getting concerned about the number of columns in the tables as the number of preferences is increasing. Also, this strategy leads to many joins if I need to get all values for a single user.

I'd like to find out the most normalized way of representing this data. Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to find out the most normalized way of representing this data.

Well, from what you describe, you seem to have quite a normalized database.
What you are looking for if you want to reduce the number of joins is **denormalization**.

For instance, if you want to access a subset of those user preferences with a smaller number of joins, you might want to cache them in a UserDetails table, and link that in the User table with a UserDetailsId foreign key.

This might actually be feasible in case you have a subset of seldom-changing values (for instance one's religion does not often change).

The drawback is that in case one of these changes you might have to change the info in two places (depending on if you want to also keep the normalized version of that data or not).

I hope this helps. Feel free to ask for additional clarification.

Comment: I'm ok with having the data in two different places. In fact, that's what I'm aiming for in order to decrease the number of columns in the Users table. So, this second table.. what would you recommend the keys be? UserId+UserDetailsId as a composite key? Then each preference as a column and each column is keyed off on to another table?

Comment: @user3308043 I was thinking of simply having a UserDetails table, with a PK (say, IdUserDetails) and do a PK_FK relationship with the Users table (have the IdUserDetails as a FK in Users). In the UserDetails table you simply keep the ACTUAL preferences (no FKs), just cache (copy) the actual data ('Christian', instead of an Id like 3)

Comment: and each preference as a column that's keyed off to another table?

Comment: Not necessarily. As I was saying, you now have a table, say Religion, where you have entries like: 1, Christian; 2, Muslim; 3, Jewish. In the Users table you have ReligionId FK, which takes values 1 through 3. Say you have a dozen other preferences stored in the same manner, which usually don't change much. UserDetails could be something like this: 1, 'Christian', 'Vegetarian', etc. with actual data in it. Then link it to the Users table by its Id. Basically UserDetails can be a cache of actual preference data.

Comment: What I have now is a table called Religion that does do just that. In the Users table, there are a number of these preferences that key to the different tables (Religion, etc). Are you suggesting a serialized UserDetails table?

Comment: I don't think the number of joins is my primary concern. My real concern is the width of the Users table. I don't want a table with 65 columns and as many joins. I could live with another table and still keep it join-heavy.